# java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to "MODEL"

Tags: android, kotlin, dictionary, mutablelist

I have this issue. I'm trying generate a map function with a my model PRODUCTS, but I have this error message `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to` I'm getting info from Firebase.
Can somebody help me? I attach my code

```
fun getDeliveryList(userId: String): LiveData<MutableList<Invoice>> {
        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Invoice>>()
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Constants.ENVIRONMENT).document("users").collection("users").document(userId).collection("invoices").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            val invoices = mutableListOf<Invoice>()
            for(document in result) {
                val uuid = document.getString("uuid")
                val invoiceURL = document.getString("invoiceURL")
                val products = document.get("products") as MutableList<Product>
                val createdAt = document.getString("createdAt")
                val isSponsor = document.getString("isSponsor")
                val invoice = Invoice(uuid!!, invoiceURL!!, products, createdAt!!, isSponsor!!)
                invoices.add(invoice)
            }
            mutableData.value = invoices
        }
        return mutableData
    }
```

I'm trying convert. to ListArray and Array

Comment: Can you please add the error stack trace from the logcat ?

Comment: This message -> java.lang.ClassCastException : java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.kevinhomorales.providerskotlin.owner.products.list.model.Product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code I can understand that all but one of the param is an Array which is the products itself.

So we will have to ensure that it is casted correctly.
We will use generic List type for Products to be safe.

```
val products = data["products"] as List<*>
```

Then afterwards we can iterate through this generic list:

```
 val pList = (prod as List<Map<String, Any>>).map { it ->
        Product(it["productName"] as String, it["productive"] as Double)
     }
```

Comment: This is the message in the logcat -> java.lang.ClassCastException : java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.kevinhomorales.providerskotlin.owner.products.list.model.Product

It shows all the items of each product but when you implement a map it explodes. In console if I can see each item

Comment: Okay it is now getting simpler. It is because the data you are getting is in the form of 'HashMap' and not 'Product'.